# How to take multiple variables that read from text files and put them into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Creating a Discord bot using node.js and discord.js and am fairly new to JavaScript. I have made a basic bot that works how I want it to, but am looking to find better ways to make the code efficient, yet concise. I have multiple variables that read from text files and was told that an array could help, only knowing basic arrays I couldn't really find tips on how to still make the array elements read from the specified text files.

I don't know much about arrays, so I haven't tried much. I was just told that arrays could help make my code concise.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const colors = require("colors");

var help = fs.readFileSync("./text/help.txt", "utf8");
var FUN = fs.readFileSync("./text/fun.txt", "utf8");
var MEME = fs.readFileSync("./text/meme.txt", "utf8");
var hello = fs.readFileSync("./text/hello.txt", "utf8");
var GAMES = fs.readFileSync("./text/games.txt", "utf8");
var music = fs.readFileSync("./text/music.txt", "utf8");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(colors.green("Connected as " + client.user.tag));
    client.user.setPresence({
        'game' : {
            'name' : 'Checking...',
            'type' : 'Playing'
        }
    })

    try {
        client.on("message", function(message) {
            var input = message.content.toUpperCase();

            if(input === "!help".toUpperCase()) {
                message.channel.send(help);
            }
            if(input === "!FUN".toUpperCase()){
                message.channel.send(FUN);
            }
            if(input === "!MEME".toUpperCase()){
                message.channel.send(MEME);
            }
            if(input === "!hello".toUpperCase()){
                message.channel.send(hello);
            }
            if(input === "!GAMES".toUpperCase()){
                message.channel.send(GAMES);
            }
            if(input === "!music".toUpperCase()){
                message.channel.send(music);
            }
        })
    }
    catch(E){
        console.log(E);
    }
})

client.login('token');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the code more concise and readable by using es6 and a bit of logic refactor.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const colors = require('colors')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client()

const files = [
  { name: 'help', path: './text/help.txt' },
  { name: 'fun', path: './text/fun.txt' },
  { name: 'meme', path: './text/meme.txt' },
  { name: 'hello', path: './text/hello.txt' },
  { name: 'games', path: './text/games.txt' },
  { name: 'music', path: './text/music.txt' }
]

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(colors.green(`Connected as ${client.user.tag}`))

  client.user.setPresence({
    game: { name: 'Checking...', type: 'Playing' }
  })

  try {
    client.on('message', message => {
      const input = message.content.toUpperCase()

      const { path } = files.find(({ name }) => name.toUpperCase() === input.substring(1))
      const response = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8')

      message.channel.send(response)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})

client.login('token')
```

As you can see, you get fewer lines of code and better readability.

To summarize the changes, use an array of objects to define your `name` and `path` of files, then when a message event occurs you find and read the right file by using the `.find()` method to compare the file `name` against the user `input` and return to the user the file content value.

You can see a good overview of es6 features in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features).